# Swiper, cannot make gallery thumbs move how to fix?

Tags: javascript, html, swiper.js

On click thumbs picture is showing as needed, but thumb itselfs not move, i have more thumbs than displayed, when i click on thumb she must move like was clicked next button**

```
let galleryThumbs = new Swiper('.gallery-thumbs', {
    spaceBetween: 10,
    slidesPerView: 2,
    loop: true,
    freeMode: false,
    watchSlidesVisibility: true,
    watchSlidesProgress: true,
    slideToClickedSlide: true,
    loopedSlides: 5
});
let galleryTop = new Swiper('.gallery-top', {
    spaceBetween: 10,
    loopedSlides: 5,
    loop:true,
    thumbs: {
      swiper: galleryThumbs,
    },
});
```

This is my  html (it render simple swiper-slide)

```
 <div class="swiper-container gallery-top">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            [[getImageList?
              &docid=`[[*id]]`
              &limit=`0`
              &tvname=`img-slider`
              &tpl=`@CODE: <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="/[[+home_img]]" alt="[[*pagetitle]]"></div>`
            ]]
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='swiper-container gallery-thumbs'>
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        [[getImageList?
          &docid=`[[*id]]`
          &limit=`0`
          &tvname=`img-slider`
          &tpl=`@CODE: <div class="swiper-slide"><div class="small_body"><img src="/[[+home_img]]" alt="[[*pagetitle]]"></div></div>`
        ]] 
    </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy bro_)) add this line to your code and will make it move! `galleryTop.controller.control = galleryThumbs;`